# Book relating to the symbiotic relationship between a human, a sentient pyramid, tiger and others

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the book in the 1960's. The human suffers harm and is protected by the sentient pyramid which assimilates him.  The pyramid also harbours other identities.  Each identity is used to overcome a particular problem that is encountered.

I have little recollection other than the book cover had the pyramid on it.  Possibly the cover was orange and it was published in paperback.

I believe it was first published in the 1960's.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to remember anything about how the cover looked?  Check out the other [suggestions for good story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: i'm curious which cover it was you had? http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?14875

Comment: @SteveV Wow, that's a lot of covers. Is that common?

Comment: Based on the description, probably [this one](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/4/4d/THWRWLFPRN1971.jpg)

Comment: The cover was the paperback UK one by Pan Publisher in 1971.  This link may show it: https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/563018684520906/

Comment: @Doc has it.  Not orange!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this could be 'The Werewolf Principle' by Clifford Simak, published in 1967

An amnesiac astronaut returns to Earth, and discovers he shares his body with alien beings which were assimilated as a means of learning about them when he was exploring their planets. One alien form is a pyramid.

Comment: Martin. It is! Many thanks. I've been trying to find this book for months. Well done.

Comment: Thought I recognised that name! One edition has a terrifying cover by the great Ian Miller